# Error enabling SpringBeanAutowiringSupport within a JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jax-ws

I am trying to enable Spring autowiring support in my webservice, following the lines of

```
public class MyService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements SomeInterface {

private Dao dao;

@Autowired
public void setDao(Dao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}
```

With the MyService class annotated with

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "SomeInterfacePath")
```

However, when I try and run this, I get a

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()Lorg/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext;
at org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.<init>(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:68)
```

error, which I haven't been able to find a resolution to. I'm using Spring 3.0 jars and apache-cxf. Spring autowiring works elsewhere in my project but doesn't seem to play nicely here. Any ideas as to what is going on? I have a a jaxws endpoint defined in my appConfig as

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="myendpoint" 
    implementor="MyService" 
    address="/helloworld
    />
```

Comment: Smells like a Spring version clash to me.  Make sure you only have the Spring 3.0 JARs. Check the CXF JARs to make sure there's no copies of Spring hidden away in there.

Comment: Thanks, turns out an older version of the Spring framework jar was being used hence the clash.

Comment: It's a good idea to add that as an answer and accept it, for other users of the site to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently, Apache CXF pulled Spring 2.5.5 as a maven dependency.
However, CXF Version 2.3 and newer use Spring 3.

- [Apache CXF parent pom 2.2.1](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/cxf-parent/2.2.1/cxf-parent-2.2.1.pom):

  ```
  <spring.version>2.5.5</spring.version>
  ```
- [Apache CXF parent pom 2.3](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/cxf-parent/2.3.0/cxf-parent-2.3.0.pom):

  ```
  <spring.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
  ```

Both include a `<dependencymanagement>` section that ties Spring to the specified version.